# HR tag to cover whole page?

Tags: html, css

I am using HR tag in my HTML page. But the horizontal line is not covering the whole page along X axis. There is a gap at left and right both. How can I fill this gap?

For example, below is a sample code -

```
<html>
   <hr>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following -> [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lloanalas/bxcLV/)

You have two options that I know of anyways - Using a horizontal line or a div with a top or bottom border.

The reason why you have a space or gap is because browsers comes with different pre-set settings - so you need to set margin and padding to zero. Take a look at the demo.

CSS

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
hr {
    margin-top: 30px;
    /*so you can see it in demo */
    width: 100%
}
.demo {
    position: relative; /*so I could use 'top: 30px' */
    top: 30px;
    /*so you can see it in demo*/
    width: 100%;
    border-top:1px solid black;
}
```

HTML

```
<hr/>
<div class="demo"></div>
```

Edit: As Ojdo commented, you CAN reset before working on a project using something like this [Meyer's Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) OR you can make it 'cross-browser' compatible and use [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) from Necolas - this basically tries to make your default css look consistent among several browsers. The choice is ultimately up to you. Start from the ground up or start with something somewhat consistent.

Comment: Instead of using a pure maring/padding reset, provide cross-browser defaults like [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css) does.

Comment: What if he doesn't want to reset all his defaults? I could however mention it to him.

Comment: He might not, but IMHO `* { /* anything */ }` already has severe effects on any defaults. Nevertheless, good answer.

Comment: Thanks LIon, let me give a try. I will let you know the result in a moment.

Comment: There ya go Ojdo ^-^. You are totally right. It's a matter of preference though, so ultimately up to him ^-^ - We at least informed him of the possibilities right?

Comment: Thank you guys, your answer is really helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

that's because of the margins of the body. try this:

```
<html>
    <body style="margin:0;">
    <hr>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

put this css on the hr:

```
hr {
  margin-left: -8px;
  margin-right: -8px;
}
```

This happens as there is always automatic margin

Here is a fiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ha97t/

Answer (score 0):

The gaps are caused by the default margin of 8px for the `body` element (which is a common browser default and described both in CSS 2.1 and in HTML5 CR).

You can override the horizontal margins of `body` rather simply:

```
body { margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0 }
```

It is possible to use more extensive overrides, like “CSS resets”, but they could affect your page layout in many ways and do not contribute to solving this problem any better than simply overriding the specific properties for `body`.

However, removing those margins means that text will run from the left edge of to right edge, often making letters touch the edges. So if you wish to make the horizontal rule extend across the page without affecting anything, set negative margins on it. Then it is best to set the `body` margins explicitly (to guard against browsers not implementing them according to common practice):

```
body { margin: 8px }
hr { margin-left: -8px; margin-right: 8px }
```